# Do-While Loop When Media Player Is Playing

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, do-while

In my app there is a "Start" button.

The desire result is whenever the **media player is playing**,the text of the button should be change to "Stop", and when the music stops the button text should change back to "Start".

I tried doing "Do While Loop" as a solution, but even when media player **isn't playing**,the text is changed.

- Is this the right solution ?
- Why does it work even when `mainViewModel.mediaPlayer.isPlaying` is false?

This is what I tried:

```
private fun trackPlayButtonTransformation() {

    do {
        rootView.speakButton.text = "Stop"

    } while (mainViewModel.mediaPlayer.isPlaying)

}
```

mainViewModel.mediaPlayer:

```
var mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In a do while, the first instruction is ran no matter what, therein lies your problem. Do a regular while

private fun trackPlayButtonTransformation() {

```
    while (mainViewModel.mediaPlayer.isPlaying) {
        rootView.speakButton.text = "Stop"
}
```

}

Even this is clearly missing, you want to set the text to Play if the condition is'nt met.

You should probably use an actionListener on the button itself, and do a switch

```
const button = findById...... You should be able to find that easily.

button.addEventListener('click', buttonIsClicked())

private buttonIsClicked () {
   if ( mainViewModel.mediaPlayer.isPlaying ) {
      // stop that song
      // change the text
   }
   else {
      // play that song
      // change the text
   }
}
```

this is a rought draft, but this kind of is how I would do a play button.

Comment: This will lock up the thread the whole time the player is playing.

Comment: I imagine you mean about the while part, I would advise against using a loop to verify wether a song is playing and fall back on the eventListener method instead personally. I was only suggesting why it registered as playing in the first place.